# Como posso trocar a parte ( "*.jpg", "*.mp4", "*.doc") por uma variável?

Tags: vb.net

Como posso trocar a parte `"*.jpg", "*.mp4", "*.doc"` por uma variavel? Eu tentei algumas coisas como: `Dim var As String = "*.jpg, *.mp4, *.doc"` ou `Dim var As String = ".jpg .mp4 .doc", ...`, mas não consegui.

```
For Each arquivo In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.jpg", "*.mp4", "*.doc")
        'value
    Next
```

**Edit:**

O que eu gostaria é de fazer algo parecido:

`Dim var As String = "*.mkv, *.mp4, *.avi"`

E em todas as vezes que eu precisar de usar:

```
FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.jpg", "*.mp4", "*.doc")
```

Eu simplesmente faça:

```
FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho, FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories,var)
```

Para que quando eu tenha que mudar uma das extensões eu não tenha que mudar uma por uma em todas as vezes que eu tiver usado  o `FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu não entendi muito bem o que você quis dizer com:

> [...] trocar a parte `"*.jpg", "*.mp4", "*.doc"` por uma variavel [...]

mas, entendi que você quer listar determinados tipos de arquivos de um caminho específico, incluindo suas subpastas.

Pelo que entendi, e testei, o método `FileSystem.GetFiles()` não aceita múltiplos tipos de arquivos no parâmetro `wildcards`, para filtrar a lista de arquivos, então, uma solução seria você criar um array com a lista de tipos que quer filtrar e chamar o método `FileSystem.GetFiles()` múltiplas vezes, para cada tipo de arquivo.

Ficaria assim:

```
Dim wildcards As String() = {"*.jpg",
                             "*.mp4",
                             "*.doc"}

For Each wildcard As String In wildcards
   For Each arquivo In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho,
                                                  FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories,
                                                  wildcard)
      ' Faz algo com o arquivo retornado.
   Next
Next
```

**Edição**

Respondendo à alteração da pergunta, a sua variável pode ser o `Array` que sugeri na primeira versão da resposta:

```
Dim curingas As String() = {"*.jpg",
                            "*.mp4",
                            "*.doc"}
```

Ou poderia ser um `List`, que fica fácil remover ou adicionar extensões:

```
Dim curingas As New List(Of String)({"*.jpg",
                                     "*.mp4",
                                     "*.doc"})

' Remove algumas extensões da lista.
curingas.Remove("*.jpg")
curingas.Remove("*.doc")
' Adiciona novas extensões à lista.
curingas.Add("*.mkv")
curingas.Add("*.avi")
```

Ou poderia até ser um `String` mesmo, como você queria inicialmente, que poderia ser transformado em um array, usando o caractere *pipe* (ou qualquer outro) como separador:

```
Dim curingasStr As String = "*.jpg|*.mp4|*.doc"

Dim curingasArray = curingasStr.Split("|")
```

Mas, como eu disse anteriormente, o método `FileSystem.GetFiles()` não aceita múltiplos tipos de arquivos no parâmetro `wildcards`, então você poderia encapsular a chamada ao método, mais ou menos assim:

```
Public Function ObterArquivos(caminho As String,
                              curingas As List(Of String)
                             ) As List(Of String)

   Dim arquivosRetorno As New List(Of String)

   For Each curinga As String In curingas
      For Each arquivo In FileIO.FileSystem.GetFiles(caminho,
                                                     FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories,
                                                     curinga)
         arquivosRetorno.Add(arquivo)
      Next
   Next

   Return arquivosRetorno

End Function
```

E poderia até ter uma versão de sobrecarga (*overload*) da função, para usar a variável de extensões no tipo `String`, como você queria. Essa versão transformaria a variável `String` com as extensões em um `List` e chamaria a versão original da função:

```
' Versão de sobrecarga (overload) da função ObterArquivos().
Public Function ObterArquivos(caminho As String, curingas As String) As List(Of String)

   Dim curingasArray As String() = curingas.Split("|")
   Dim curingasLista As List(Of String) = curingasArray.ToList()

   Return ObterArquivos(caminho, curingasLista)

End Function
```

Comment: O problema é que eu uso essas parte algumas varias vezes, e eu gostaria de fazer isso que eu falei para criar uma única variável de controle que quando alterada mudasse todas ao mesmo tempo. Com essa solução eu teria que mudar muita coisa. Mas não tem jeito mesmo então né?

Comment: O que você usa várias vezes? A variável com os tipos de arquivos? A sua variável pode ser o array, ou então você pode usar um `List`, ou pode usar `String` mesmo, com um separador, e fazer um `Split()` depois. Mas, precisaria entender exatamente o que você quer, que eu ainda não entendi direito. Você tem algum outro trecho de código para exemplificar como quer usar a variável?

Comment: Editei a  pergunta.

Comment: Li sua edição da pergunta, mas, a resposta continua sendo basicamente a mesma. Como eu disse, o `FileSystem.GetFiles()` não aceita um filtro com múltiplas extensões de arquivo, então você teria que chamar esse método para cada extensão que quiser pesquisar. Mas, a sua variável poderia ser o array que está no código que sugeri, que podia até ser um `List` ou até um `String`, como você estava planejando.

Comment: @LucasPedro, editei a resposta, veja se agora responde suas dúvidas.